# 'train' and 'class' have different lengths knn

Tags: r, knn

Getting the good ol' " 'train' and 'class' have different lengths " error. Please advise. I also probably shouldn't be getting a perfectly classified test set using one variable as a classifier. Now note that it is my intention to use one variable. So please address the " 'train' and 'class' have different lengths " error.

```
install.packages("class")
library("class")

mydata <- read.table("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data", sep=",", header=FALSE)

index <- 1:nrow(mydata)
testindex <- sample(index, trunc(length(index)/4))
testset <-mydata[testindex,]
trainset <- mydata[-testindex,]

#Iris type classifed by sepal length

kblah <- knn(train = trainset['V1'],  
         test=testset['V1'],     
         cl=as.factor(testset[['V5']]) ,
         k=1, l=0, prob=F, use.all=T)

#Iris type classified by sepal width

kblah2 <- knn(train = trainset['V2'],  
         test=testset['V2'],     
         cl=as.factor(testset[['V5']]) ,
         k=1, l=0, prob=F, use.all=T)

#Iris type classified by petal length

kblah3 <- knn(train = trainset['V3'],  
         test=testset['V3'],     
         cl=as.factor(testset[['V5']]) ,
         k=1, l=0, prob=F, use.all=T)

#Iris type classified by petal width 

kblah4 <- knn(train = trainset['V4'],  
         test=testset['V4'],     
         cl=as.factor(testset[['V5']]) ,
         k=1, l=0, prob=F, use.all=T)

plot(kblah)
plot(kblah2)
plot(kblah3)
plot(kblah4)

table(kblah)
table(kblah2)
table(kblah3)
table(kblah4)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you exactly what's wrong. In the `?knn` help page, it describes the `cl=` parameter as "factor of true classifications of training set" and yet you are passing in values from the testset. That's just wrong. It should be `cl=as.factor(trainset[['V5']])`